# Flutter iOS app throws "PathAccessException" when saving a file

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I want to create a pdf file into a directory that users choose in Flutter.

This works well for iOS simulator. But, when I try to save the file on real device the app throws "**PathAccessException**".

This also works for Android for some directories. But, also in Android, some paths are protected.

I am using **file_picker** package's **getDirectoryPath** method to get the path.

I couldn't also find any appropriate permission to get from the users. Is there any permission I should add?

Comment: Which path was chosen by the user?

Comment: It throws on any path. For example, I created a folder, on On My Iphone section, named "test", and selected this path.

Comment: This path is? Full path please.

Answer (score 0):

`file_picker`'s `getDirectoryPath()` is meant for reading the selected directory rather than modifying it. On iOS it uses the [`initWithDocumentTypes:inMode:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentpickerviewcontroller/1618678-initwithdocumenttypes?language=objc) which

> Creates and returns a document picker that **can open or copy** the specified file types.

You'd need to use the `saveFile()` method from the package, but it's not supported on iOS and Android, probably due to how these OSes handle their filesystem access permissions.

If you want to save a file, you may:

- use `path_provider` and its [`getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/path_provider/latest/path_provider/getApplicationDocumentsDirectory.html) and save files there, although they won't be easily accessible outside of the app (from what I know)
- on iOS, use the [`share_plus`](https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus) package's [`Share.shareXFiles`](https://pub.dev/documentation/share_plus/latest/share_plus/Share/shareXFiles.html) to *share* the file, which will show a native sheet where user may choose to save file to a directory they like.